# How to set the canvas background color for AvalonEdit in C#

Tags: c#, canvas, background, avalonedit

I want to have different background colors for the AvalonEdit control but although I see solutions for coloring individual lines I cannot seem to find one just to set the entire background color. Usually this is a simple task in most controls. The obvious property seemed to be

ICSharpCode.AvalonEdit.TextEditor.Background

For example if my AvalonEdit control is called "TheEditor" I wish a line something like

TheEditor.Background=.....

But I cannot seem to get it to accept anything even when setting it to a new instance of it's class.

I am very new to C# (this is my first project) and can't help thinking I'm missing something fundamental.

Answer (score 2):

I've found the correct usage for this property;

Example :

```
         ThisEditor.Background =  System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Red;
```

There was another brush type within my scope (System.Windows.Drawing.Brush) that was also causing some confusion until I fully qualified the path from "Brushes.Red" to "System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Red"